# Browserify:Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory error

Tags: node.js, module, backend, browserify, referenceerror

Browserify:Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory error,
facing this issue while im trying to bundle my index.js which contains express and mongoose so that i can avoid browsers require is not defined error
here is my index.js script

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

main().catch(err => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/contact');
}

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    phone: String,
    mail: String,
    desc: String
});

const contact = mongoose.model('contact', contactSchema);

// Uncomment the following line to use body-parser middleware
// const bodyparser = require("body-parser")

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    const { name, phone, mail, desc } = req.body;

    const newContact = new contact({
        name,
        phone,
        mail,
        desc
    });

    newContact.save()
        .then(() => {
            res.send("Form submitted successfully");
        })
        .catch(() => {
            res.status(400).send("Unable to submit form");
        });
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

[screenshot of this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LOsU.png)

i previously started learning backend and this problem is causing frustration to me, i looked for the solutions on the internet and youtube and couldn't find it anywhere,any help in solving this problem is highly apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Before you read

> Node and Express apps run on a machine/computer not inside a browser. So you have to use `npm` to run those. Here's a [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70130437/11727541) that explains everything. As you just started with backend, this might be new to you

## Answer

I don't think browserify is the right tool to bundle a server side application. It's better to use [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io).

Here's a [good article](https://devtails.medium.com/bundling-your-node-js-express-app-with-esbuild-5aecc36c5047) I found that shows how to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much brother using esbuild solved my problem, getting started with it was a bit confusing for me as i needed to do some changes in package.json but anyways  im able to get my form working.....thanks

Comment: I tried several build tools for bundling a nodejs app. All were more work and complexity than this one. This was super simple to get to work.